# Nothing prints on console in SFML

Tags: c++, console, sfml

I am trying SFML, but got some strange issue,

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(1100, 600), "SFML - learning");

    while (window.isOpen()) {
       std::cout << "Inside the game loop.\n";       // issue is here
       sf::Event event;

       while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
          if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
             window.close();
             exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
    }

    window.clear();
    window.display();
}

return 0;
```

}
'''

when I do compile/Link and go for output, nothing prints on my console.It runs successfully but on console should also print "Inside the game loop.", but it does nothing. Here is  what I am doing (I am using mingw compiler)

g++ -IC:\SFML-2.5.1\include -c main.cpp  -o out.o

g++ -LC:\SFML-2.5.1\lib .\out.o -o app.exe -lmingw32 -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-main -mwindows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-mwindows` means "don't open a console for my application". You might want to remove it in debug builds.